# Does require.js check for an already loaded js file?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I am showing different type of HTML 5 charts as a result i have made seperate js files for each chart type so that i can load selectively. Have heard a lot about require.js hence tried my hand at it. I am fairly new to this hence am not sure whether the way i have implemented them is proper..Below is the function that i call to build my charts:

```
      function buildChart(podObj) {

        switch (podObj.PodAttributes.type) {
            case "ColumnChart":

                  requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/column.chart.js"], function () {
                var objChart = ColumnChart.getInstance();
                onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
                  });
                break;
            case "dataGrid":
                 requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/grid.js"], function () {
                var objChart = DataGrid.getInstance();
                onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
                 });
                break;
            case "lineChart":
                requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/line.chart.js"], function () {
                var objChart = LineChart.getInstance();
                onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
                 });
                break;
            case "pieChart":
                 requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/pie.chart.js"], function () {
                var objChart = PieChart.getInstance();
                onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
                  });
                break;
        }
    }
    function onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart) {

        objChart.BaseViewRef.Variables.ViewProperties = podObj;
        objChart.Build();
    }
```

Is this a proper way to use require.js? I didnt want to go for a modular pattern at the moment. Another thing is that If the case for a Column Chart repeats will require.js repeatedly load the column.chart.js file and can i skip the loading?